# how to avoid Dropbox revisions purge after 30 days?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, dropbox-api, dropbox-php, revisions

I try to disable purge after 30 days in Dropbox via php sdk.
I can do it in Google drive using `keepForever` to `true` so it wont purge revisions after 30 days.https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions#resource-representations

in same way how to do it dropbox i have searched a lot but could not find a solution and also if once purged can i take that file via code because here i saw
https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#metadata-details
i can get meta data of deprecated revisions so can I download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to retain or retrieve older revisions on demand like this.

Note that accounts with the "Extended Version History" feature will retain revisions longer than 30 days though:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/113